# Pivoting COVID-19 JH Data to Time Series Rows

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I am trying to pivot the Johns Hopkins Data so that date columns are rows and the rest of the information stays the same. The first seven columns should stay columns, but the remaining columns (date columns) should be rows. Any help would be appreciated.

**Load and Filter data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
deaths_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv'
confirmed_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv'

dea = pd.read_csv(deaths_url)
con = pd.read_csv(confirmed_url)

dea = dea[(dea['Province_State'] == 'Texas')]
con = con[(con['Province_State'] == 'Texas')]
```

**View recency of data and pivot**

```
# get the most recent data of data
mostRecentDate = con.columns[-1] # gets the columns of the matrix

# show the data frame
con.sort_values(by=mostRecentDate, ascending = False).head(10)

# save this index variable to save the order.
index = data.columns.drop(['Province_State']) 

# The pivot_table method will eliminate duplicate entries from Countries with more than one city
data.pivot_table(index = 'Admin2', aggfunc = sum)

# formatting using a variety of methods to process and sort data
finalFrame = data.transpose().reindex(index).transpose().set_index('Admin2').sort_values(by=mostRecentDate, ascending=False).transpose()
```

The resulting data frame looks like this, however it did not preserve any of the date times

[image]

I have also tried:

```
date_columns = con.iloc[:, 7:].columns
con.pivot(index = date_columns, columns = 'Admin2', values = con.iloc[:, 7:])
ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

Edit:
As per guidance I tried the melt command listed in the first answer and it does not create rows of dates, it just removed all other non-date values.

```
date_columns = con.iloc[:, 7:].columns
con.melt(id_vars=date_columns)
```

**The end result should look like this:**

```
  Date  iso2    iso3    code3   FIPS    Admin2  Province_State  Country_Region  Lat Long_   Combined_Key
1/22/2020   US  USA 840 48001   Anderson    Texas   US  31.81534745 -95.65354823    Anderson, Texas, US
1/22/2020   US  USA 840 48003   Andrews Texas   US  32.30468633 -102.6376548    Andrews, Texas, US
1/22/2020   US  USA 840 48005   Angelina    Texas   US  31.25457347 -94.60901487    Angelina, Texas, US
1/22/2020   US  USA 840 48007   Aransas Texas   US  28.10556197 -96.9995047 Aransas, Texas, US
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Great example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

Example:

```
In [41]: cheese = pd.DataFrame({'first': ['John', 'Mary'],
   ....:                        'last': ['Doe', 'Bo'],
   ....:                        'height': [5.5, 6.0],
   ....:                        'weight': [130, 150]})
   ....: 

In [42]: cheese
Out[42]: 
  first last  height  weight
0  John  Doe     5.5     130
1  Mary   Bo     6.0     150

In [43]: cheese.melt(id_vars=['first', 'last'])
Out[43]: 
  first last variable  value
0  John  Doe   height    5.5
1  Mary   Bo   height    6.0
2  John  Doe   weight  130.0
3  Mary   Bo   weight  150.0

In [44]: cheese.melt(id_vars=['first', 'last'], var_name='quantity')
Out[44]: 
  first last quantity  value
0  John  Doe   height    5.5
1  Mary   Bo   height    6.0
2  John  Doe   weight  130.0
3  Mary   Bo   weight  150.0
```

In your case, you need to be operating on a dataframe (i.e. `con` or `finalframe` or wherever your date column is). For example:

```py
con.melt(id_vars=date_columns)
```

See specific example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt).

Comment: I have already tried: `date_columns = con.iloc[:, 7:].columns` then 
`con.pivot(index = date_columns, columns = 'Admin2', values = con.iloc[:, 7:].values)` however I get an error: `ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only`

Comment: Your approach (of using `pivot`) is not the same as `melt`... I've updated my answer to include an example. See link at the bottom as well.

Comment: And make sure you're working on the correct dataframe that contains the necessary index columns

Comment: I tried `con.melt(id_vars=date_columns)` after designating date columns and it just removed all nondate values. please see original post. thanks.